# PHP server unable to receive javascript object using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hello i am trying to send fields from a from that i saved in a javascript object to a php server. I am using ajax but when i try to receive the object in php i get a length of 0 when debugging. Basically i can't receive the data. Please what did  i do wrong.

```
Javascript code:
    //fields from from saved in an object.
    var obj={
      'user_name': username,
      'pwd': psswd1,
      'user_email': email,
      'user_phone': mobile,
      'sec_quest1': question1,
      'ans1': answer1,
      'sec_quest2': question2,
      'ans2': answer2,
      'user_address': address,
      'user_userInfo': user_info
  };

   console.log(obj);

   var data = JSON.stringify(obj)
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
//document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    alert(xhttp.responseText);
   }
 } 
 xhttp.open("POST", "server.php", true);
 xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 xhttp.send(data);
}
```

php code:

```
<?php
  $obj = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
 echo 'Name: '.sizeof($obj);
?>
```

It displays a size of zero meaning it's not receiving the data. Please what did i do wrong

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST)`. From what I see you're trying to access the form field named `data` and that isn't sent, because you didn't define it.

Comment: @macılay i took the variables name and stored it in a javascript object and in turn used ajax to Post the data to Php.

Comment: @ma cılay is correct.  You can just access the fields like $_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_phone'] etc.  There is no $_POST['data'] variable

Comment: still `$_POST['data']` means that you are trying to access a form field value that was defined under the name `data`

Comment: @macılay oh i see but if i want to pass the js object after serializing it how do i access in post? is that possbile?

Comment: K, I answered below, should work

Comment: @macılay so $_POST is only meant for retrieving datas from the form

Comment: Yes. When you submit a form your browser generates a query string in the form of `name1=value1&name2=value2` and so on. I think your json data was sent but not in the form of a query string. So the data wasn't available under the name `data`. I wonder what would happen if you used `xhttp.send("data="+data)`

Comment: @macılay ok will try that approach and see what happens

Comment: @macılay no that didn't work

Comment: then we learned both something new today :)

Comment: @macılay yes and thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant access the post variable when posting JSON to the server so you need to do this.

```
$str = file_get_contents('php://input'); //($_POST doesn't work here)
$response = json_decode($str, true);
```

Then retrieve the fields

```
$name = $response['user_name'];
$phone = $response['user_phone'];
// etc
// or just $response[0], $response[1], $response[2] etc etc
```

Basically the same answer as techblu3 above, but a little more detailed.

Comment: i wasn't allowed to use JQuery and i'm learning javascript purely first before learning jquery

Comment: it worked thanks. So $_POST is only meant for retrieving data from the forms

Comment: Yup.  Anytime the request is application/x-www-form-urlencoded as opposed to application/json

Comment: so whenever i intend to use ajax its better to use file_get_content especially when the content is in json

Comment: Yes, but only if you have to use json for any reason.  If you have a choice.  Posting the form via  application/x-www-form-urlencoded is better.  That way you just serialize the form, and post. The best option in terms of cross browser compatibility etc, was the Jquery answer I posted earlier.  But since you can't use jquery and need to post JSON this is what you're left with

Comment: so jquery serializes it for you without going through the hassle of writing your own serializer function. Did i get that right?

Comment: Yes, if you include the Jquery library.  All you need to do is grab the form by its id, and run the serialize method on it  ie.. var the_form = $('#your_form_id').serialize();   Then you would post that form using the post method.  $.post('yourserver.php', the_form);   You also get all the wierd cross browser issues with XHttp requests out of the way, as Jquery abstracts all that complexity away.

Answer (score 2):

You might be posting raw data, that can be accessed in php in this way

```
    $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
    // true parameter is used to decode as array
    // you can make it false to use object
    echo $obj["user_name"];
```

Comment: but i used JSON.stringify to pass the object as a string

Comment: thanks. So which approach is better between file_get_contents and _$POST?

Comment: It depends, if you're using json, file_get_contents("php://input"), is good
I'd recommend this

Comment: xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
and using stringify means you are passing raw data to server that is why it is available as raw input in php.

Comment: thanks for the input. but isn't most data sent using json nowadays

Comment: Most data is sent from server to client as JSON.  Not the other way round.  Unless youre posting to a third party API or something. The majority of posted data, specially to your own site, will still be in the form format as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: indeed if you were using front end framework such as angularjs , it sends request as json by default, and yes json is indeed the most common way to pass data between services(server to server ) as well as front end and server(normally api)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be serializing your data so you can send it with header x-www-form-urlencoded.

```
 serialize = function(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for (var p in obj)
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
   }
  return str.join("&");
 }
 var obj = {
  'user_name': 'John Doe',
  'user_email': 'john@doe.net',
  'user_phone': '2122221111',
 };

  var params = serialize(obj);
  var url = "https://url.net";


  console.log(params);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);

  //Send the proper header information along with the request
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  xhr.send(params);
```

Your PHP file would would include

```
 <?php echo 'Name: '.sizeof($_POST); ?>
```